# Save an aspx page in session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a login page that return the userName to a page called User.aspx.  The User.aspx shows the information about the user based on a sql select. I fill 12 labels on the page with the result of the select. I want to keep the information of my 12 labels if the user Quits and enter again in the page.

I save my session

```
       Session("UserPage") = (litHello.Text And litAddresse.Text And litAnimalGenre.Text And litCouriel.Text And litNomAnimal.Text And litPays.Text And litPostalCode.Text And litProvince.Text And litRace.Text And litTel.Text And litVille.Text)
```

Now how I can proceed too fill all my label with my saved session call UserPage??? That is the question !!! The code is VB.NET
Thank's for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer on your question:**

I would make a class with multiple properties and save that in the session ;)

Eg.

```
Public class PropertySession
   Public Property ID as integer
   Public Property Name as String
   Public Property Address as String
End Class
```

Then (the long way)

```
Dim currentPropertySession as PropertySession
With PropertySession
   .ID = litID.Text
   .Name = litName.Text
   .Address = litAddress.Text
End With
```

And finally store

```
Session("Property") = currentPropertySession
```

or the shorter way (still need to declare PropertySession)

```
Session("Property") = New PropertySession With { .ID = litID.Text, .Name = litName.Text, .Address = litAddress.Text}
```

You can even do this - only to be complete, but i wouldn't do this if i were you -

```
  Session("Property") = New Object With { .ID = litID.Text, .Name = litName.Text, .Address = litAddress.Text}
```

**Additional**
[There are 8 ways to store data of a user to the next page.](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/e653f028-01fb-4d0e-843b-058deae562a2/eight-different-ways-to-transfer-data-from-one-page-to-another-page.aspx)

Check out which one is good enough for you.

Comment: So I have to do one label by one ... No another way to do it in pakage??

Comment: So and how it retrieve all the information in the DirectCast??

Comment: that's another question, but check this out: PropertySession mySession = DirectCast(Session("Property"),PropertySession)

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to do it the way you have it and then when you read out the session split the values into an array and then loop through your array.  You will need to use a delimiter to separate the values so you can split them.

```
Session("UserPage") = (litHello.Text & "|" & litAddresse.Text & "|" & litAnimalGenre.Text & "|" & litCouriel.Text & "|" & litNomAnimal.Text & "|" & litPays.Text & "|" & litPostalCode.Text & "|" & litProvince.Text & "|" & litRace.Text & "|" & litTel.Text & "|" & litVille.Text)
```

The when you read out the the values:

```
dim userInfo as string() = Session("UserPage").toString().split("|")
```

Now set your labels accordingly

```
label1.text = userInfo(0)
label2.text = userInfo(1)
etc...
```

The one problem here is you have to be sure all your values in the session have a value and if they don't you fill it with an empty string `""` so that your split will populate the correct number of values.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication things you can use out of the box functionality from ASP.Net. It offers an API with standard providers like [SQL Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) etc.

By using web.config settings, you can allow users to access only certain portions of your site (like a members area). Then, if you like to query more information than the Membership Provider API allows you to, you can get the authenticated user identity (you natural key) from anywhere like:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

With this information, you can query your database.